# How can I configure the maven to cope with both corporate/VPN and public repository setups?

Tags: maven, repository, mirror, multiple-repositories

I need a setup to be able to compile a Java Maven project using either the:

- corporate Maven repository (intranet Artifactory proxying Maven Central and others)
- public Maven repositories (Central, ICM, io.confluent, etc.)

**The project POM code already references the internal corporate repository**:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>artifactory-virtual</id>
        <name>My Artifactory Repository to download</name>
        <url>https://artifactory.corporation.com/maven</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But to work with this repository requires a VPN connection that I would like to avoid.

I am trying to setup a repository mirror as using [this Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html).

Hence I am configuring in my `~/.m2/settings.xml` the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    ...
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>icm-mirror</id>
            <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*,!central</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    ...
</settings>
```

but just providing a mirror alone (for all repos except central), the project is still trying to download from the corporate repository (I am not providing any):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ibis-customer-management:
    Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.project:myproject:jar:3.7.1-SNAPSHOT:
    Failed to collect dependencies at com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:18.3.0.0:
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:18.3.0.0: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:pom:18.3.0.0 from/to artifactory-virtual (https://artifactory.corporation.com/maven):
    Transfer failed for https://artifactory.corporation.com/maven/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/18.3.0.0/ojdbc8-18.3.0.0.pom:
    Connect to artifactory.corporation.com [artifactory.corporation.com/1.2.3.4] failed:
    Operation timed out -> [Help 1]
```

The error is not fixed even if I create an active profile with an explicit entry for the ICM repository:

```
<settings>
    ...
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>icm-mirror</id>
            <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*,!central</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>not-corpnet</id>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>icm</id>
                    <name>ICM Repository</name>
                    <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>not-corpnet</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    ...
</settings>
```

If you think there might be anything else in my `settings.xml`, the above one is pretty much the complete one (without the dots, and with the correct XML namespaces.

The profile is also active and visible when I run `mvn`

```
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:active-profiles (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO]
Active Profiles for Project 'com.example.project:myproject:pom:3.7.1-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - not-corpnet (source: external)
```

How can I make my project, which has already inside its POM the corporate repository, to download artifacts from public repositories when I am not in the corporate network/VPN?

Comment: It is usually better to avoid putting repositories into the POM. If you manage them purely through the `settings.xml`, it will be easier and more transparent.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot 100% control this. I can try to push for a change in this direction but that would be the 2nd step. Now I have to live with POM + workaround in `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We finally reached an OK setup that is working the same way from both public and corporate networks by doing the following:

- the project `pom.xml` contains the required public repositories:

  ```
  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Central Repository</name>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
          <id>icm</id>
          <name>ICM Repository</name>
          <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
          <id>confluent</id>
          <name>Confluent Repository</name>
          <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
  ```

  Assuming that the project does not require non-public dependencies, this will allow "checkout and run" way of work in public environments.
- if we are inside the corporate network (with access to the private repositories) and behind the corporate proxy, we use a `settings.xml` file that each developer can use (`~/.m2/serttings.xml`) for development inside the corporate environment. This file contains `<proxies>` and `<mirrors>`:

  ```
  <mirrors>
      <mirror>
          <id>internal-repository-mirror</id>
          <name>Maven Mirror</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.corporation.com/maven</url>
          <mirrorOf>*,!confluent</mirrorOf>
      </mirror>
      <mirror>
          <id>internal-confluent-mirror</id>
          <name>Confluent Mirror</name>
          <url>https://artifactory.corporation.com/confluent-maven</url>
          <mirrorOf>confluent</mirrorOf>
      </mirror>
  </mirrors>

  <proxies>
      <proxy>
          <id>corpnet-http-proxy</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>proxy.corporation.com</host>
          <port>8079</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>artifactory.corporation.com</nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
      <proxy>
          <id>corpnet-https-proxy</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>https</protocol>
          <host>proxy.corporation.com</host>
          <port>8079</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>artifactory.corporation.com</nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
  </proxies>
  ```

No other repositories or profiles are necessary in the `settings.xml` file.

Regarding how the `settings.xml` is being exchanged in an automatic way, I use the following approach which suits my way of work where I always have a terminal open:

- when I start a terminal window/tab the `~/.bash_profile` (or equivalent) is being executed
- depending on the network I am on (public or corporate/VPN) I copy/overwrite one of the two existing `settings.xml` files I have prepared:
  ** `settings-public.xml` almost empty (might have some special repositories that I use while playing/experimenting with code)
  ** `settings-corpnet.xml` containing at least the `<mirrors>` and `<proxies>` sections pointed above